# could not open the file

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I have a server using phpJavaBrigde, and I have a problem adding a jar file:

```
require_once('Java.inc');
java_require("tciphone.jar");
```

it has an error:

```
[[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: Invoke failed: [[o:JavaBridge]]->updateJarLibraryPath((o:String)[o:String], (o:String)[o:String], (o:String)[o:String], (o:String)[o:String]). 
Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not open jar file /var/www/iphone/trescantos/tciphone.jar, reason: error in opening zip file VM: 1.6.0_20@http://java.sun.com/"
at: #-29 php.java.bridge.DynamicJavaBridgeClassLoader.checkJarFile(DynamicJavaBridgeClassLoader.java:108) #-28 php.java.bridge.JarLibraryPath.createUrls(JarLibraryPath.java:193)
#-27 php.java.bridge.JarLibraryPath.checkURLs(JarLibraryPath.java:118) #0 /usr/share/php/Java.inc(265): 
java_ThrowExceptionProxyFactory->getProxy(1, NULL, true) #1 /usr/share/php/Java.inc(417): 
java_Arg->getResult(true) #2 /usr/share/php/Java.inc(423):        
java_Client->getWrappedResult(true) #3 /usr/share/php/Java.inc(627): 
java_Client->getResult() #4 /usr/share/php/Java.inc(1631): 
java_Client->invokeMethod(0, 'updateJarLibrar...', Array)
#5 /var/www/iphone/trescantos/newIncidenceReg.php(6): java_require('tciphone.jar') 
#6 {main}]
```

The file exists  I check the permision 644 as usual.

what could it happening?

Comment: Can't help you, sorry, but while looking for a possible solution, I stumbled upon [this](http://drupal.org/node/617922) which might be helpful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, the jar file was corrupted for some reason, I create it as usual, but was corrupted.